# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException (405) File Upload

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload a csv file and then dump the header information to test if the file upload works. I can see the page and select a file to upload fine. However, when I try to submit, I am running into this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

Developer Tools outputs: `upload-report:1 POST (url)/upload-report 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Trying to research the issue shows that it may be a routes problem, but I can't seem to find one if there is.

**Routes**

```
Route:: get('upload-prescriptions', 'PrescriptionController@uploadPage')->name('upload-prescriptions');
Route:: get('upload-report', 'PrescriptionController@uploadReport')->name('upload-report');
```

**Controller**

```
public function uploadPage()
{
    return view('prescriptions.upload');
}


public function uploadReport(Request $request)
{
    $upload = $request->file('upload_file');

    $file_path = $upload->getRealPath();

    $file = fopen($file_path, 'r');

    $header = fgetcsv($file);

    dd($header);
}
```

**Blade**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['PrescriptionController@uploadReport'], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'files' => true]) !!}
    @csrf
    {{Form::file('upload_file', ['class' => 'form-control-file'])}}
    {{Form::submit('Upload File', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You have a route mismatch. It's POSTing to the URL, but you have it defined as a GET in your routes. Change it in your routes file.

Comment: @aynber comments are not for answers.  You have the correct solution, but please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route:: get('upload-report', 'PrescriptionController@uploadReport')->name('upload-report');
```

change to

```
Route::post('upload-report', 'PrescriptionController@uploadReport')->name('upload-report');
```

Because in the form you have said the method as `POST` but your route is `get`

Answer (score 0):

In your view file you have used post request form submit

```
Form::open(['action' => ['PrescriptionController@uploadReport'], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'files' => true])
```

but you defined the method in route as get method

```
Route:: get('upload-report', 'PrescriptionController@uploadReport')->name('upload-report');
```

so please change it as post request like below

```
Route::post('upload-report', 'PrescriptionController@uploadReport')->name('upload-report');
```